# Как узнать графический адаптер?

Tags: linux, c, qt

необходимо узнать видеокарту на QT(C) под linux.Пробовал найти его на примере процессора  fopen("proc/cpuinfo","rb"),но не нашел.
Подскажите,как получить название видеоадаптера?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/5417/how-to-get-the-gpu-info

Comment: Руками посмотрите файлы в `proc/*` возможно называются по другому, зависит от версии ядра.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Определить видеоадаптер можно начиная от папки `/sys/class/graphics/fb0/`

Драйвер

```
cat /sys/class/graphics/fb0/name
inteldrmfb
```

Производитель и айди устройства

```
cat /sys/class/graphics/fb0/device/device                  
0x1916
cat /sys/class/graphics/fb0/device/vendor                  
0x8086
```

0x8086 - это интел.
Если на компьютере несколько видеокарточек, то там будет `fb1` и далее.

А вот человеческие названия надо искать в файлах

```
/usr/share/hwdata/usb.ids
/usr/share/hwdata/pci.ids
```

Могут быть в папке `/usr/share/misc` 
[pci.ids в Debian](https://packages.debian.org/search?mode=path&suite=stretch&section=all&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=pci.ids)
[usb.ids в Debian](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=usb.ids&mode=path&suite=stable&arch=any)

Это что касается простых видеокарт. А **графические ускорители** смотрим в `/sys/class/drm/` аналогично способу выше. Там есть папка на каждый вывод карточки, саму карту(card0) и ускоритель (rendererD128)

Answer (score 0):

`lspci`: все что может быть связанно с VGA, DVI, HDMI перечисляет Ваши графические адаптеры

Конечно же, если у Вас интегрированный видеоадаптер. В противном случае результат может дать комманда `glxinfo | grep -i render`

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что всё адаптеры будут представлены на шине PCI?